How to Handling Multiple Toggle States in a Single Cubit
I'm experimenting with Cubit in Flutter and wanted to create a ToggleCubit that handles multiple toggle actions (e.g., toggling between true and false).
Scenario
I initially added the BlocProvider at the top level of my widget tree, specifically at the Scaffold of my screen:
BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => ToggleCubit(),
  child: const Scaffold( ...

I intended to use this Cubit for toggling the show/hide password functionality and the checkbox state. However, as expected, changing one state affected the other because they share the same Cubit instance. I understand why this happens but was looking for a way to manage each toggle independently without having to create a separate BlocProvider for each widget.
Current Implementation
Option 1: Separate BlocProvider for Each Toggle
I added a separate BlocProvider for each widget so that they have independent states. Here's how it looks:
Show/Hide Password:
BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => ToggleCubit(),
  child: BlocBuilder<ToggleCubit, bool>(
    builder: (context, isPasswordVisible) {
      return TextFormField(
        obscureText: isPasswordVisible,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Password',
          prefixIcon: Icon(PhosphorIcons.lock()),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<ToggleCubit>().toggle();
            },
            icon: Icon(isPasswordVisible
                ? PhosphorIcons.eyeSlash()
                : PhosphorIcons.eye()),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),

Checkbox:
BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => ToggleCubit(),
  child: BlocBuilder<ToggleCubit, bool>(
    builder: (context, isChecked) {
      return Checkbox(
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (_) {
          context.read<ToggleCubit>().toggle();
        },
      );
    },
  ),
),

This approach works fine for small cases, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.
Option 2: Managing Multiple States in a Single Cubit
I also considered managing both the password visibility and checkbox states within a single Cubit. I modified the state to handle multiple properties:
Cubit State:
final class ToggleState {
  final bool isChecked;
  final bool isPasswordVisible;

  ToggleState({
    this.isChecked = false,
    this.isPasswordVisible = false,
  });

  ToggleState copyWith({
    bool? isChecked,
    bool? isPasswordVisible,
  }) {
    return ToggleState(
      isChecked: isChecked ?? this.isChecked,
      isPasswordVisible: isPasswordVisible ?? this.isPasswordVisible,
    );
  }
}

Cubit Implementation:
class ToggleCubit extends Cubit<ToggleState> {
  ToggleCubit() : super(ToggleState());

  void passwordToggle() {
    emit(state.copyWith(isPasswordVisible: !state.isPasswordVisible));
  }

  void checkboxToggle() {
    emit(state.copyWith(isChecked: !state.isChecked));
  }
}

Question
I'm unsure which approach is better for managing multiple toggle states. Is it more efficient or scalable to have a separate BlocProvider for each widget, or should I manage multiple states within a single Cubit? Are there other methods or best practices that I might have overlooked?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Look, as you have mentioned in your question it can be solved by different approaches, for your question which is the best? it can be considered as opinion-based but it's not because it's more closely to design rather than personal preferences.
some people see that separating child widgets like check box and text field in your question and make a state manager for their own will lead to needless complexity
So, how could we handle it, and what are factors that decide whether to make a state managers for those child widgets or not?

it depends on, how complex is that child widget according to (it
states) if its life cycle could has many states then you should
make a separated manager for it.

if it's just toggling state and making only one cubit manage the toggle state for both check box and text field will keep it simple and clear, go on.

Thank you for the detailed explanation! I now understand that the decision is more about design considerations than personal preference. It's helpful to know that if a widget has a simple state, using a single cubit to manage it for both the checkbox and text field can keep things clean. However, for more complex widgets with multiple states, or like the entire app does the same solutions still valid.

@FatalError, yes. do what makes your system design understandable and scalable.
